# HTML Radio Buttons best practices

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I work on a large Backbone application at work. The interface is essentially a big form. We use the `name` attribute to map our inputs to our model properties so we can autosave each field on change or enter, letting Backbone do its thing. I just spent two days trying to figure out why one particular section causes the page to reload with a weird URL. The answer is obvious now, but after building a big app over 9 months, you tend to overlook the small things.

Throughout the application we use `<input>` all over the place without a wrapping `<form>`. In one case, however, we have a repeating element in the form of a Handlebars template that contains radio buttons with the same name:

```
<div id="1">
    <input type="radio" name="choose" value="yes"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choose" value="no"> No
    <input type="text">
</div>

<div id="2">
    <input type="radio" name="choose" value="yes"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choose" value="no"> No
    <input type="text">
</div>

<div id="3">
    <input type="radio" name="choose" value="yes"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choose" value="no"> No
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

The problem with this is that they get grouped together because of they all have the same `name` attribute. So, instead of getting 3 values (one for each group), we were getting 1 value (for one big group).

Since we know that radio button groups are "scoped" to the containing `<form>`, we just wrapped it:

```
<div id="1">
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="choose" value="yes"> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="choose" value="no"> No
        <input type="text">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="2">
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="choose" value="yes"> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="choose" value="no"> No
        <input type="text">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="3">
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="choose" value="yes"> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="choose" value="no"> No
        <input type="text">
    </form>
</div>
```

This works just fine for the radio buttons, but now that we have a form, hitting `enter` on the text `<input>` actually submits the form, instead of autosaving (technically, in addition to autosaving). At the time, this never even occurred to me, since we somehow managed to avoid this everywhere else in the application.

I can think of a few different solutions to this problem: setting a submit handler on the form, setting a submit handler on the text input, leaving the text input outside the form. But these seem like hacks to deal with what I would say is broken behavior. If input elements work outside of forms, then grouping input elements should work outside of forms. And since we're already using the `name` attribute (which works for everything else), unique names isn't really an option.

So is there a best practice for situations like this? Is there an element other than `<form>` that will properly scope radio buttons? Am I just going to have to live with `<form onsubmit="return false;">`?

P.S. We support IE 8+

UPDATE

This is what I ended up with:

```
<div id="1">
    <form onsubmit="return false;">
        <input type="radio" name="choose" value="yes"> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="choose" value="no"> No
    </form>

    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't the `name`s be made unique? I believe that would technically be the best 'best practice' thing to do here.

Comment: We're using the `name` property to map input fields to our model properties for autosaving. Working around that would be more work and wouldn't be any more elegant than what I'm already considering.

Comment: Updated the question to include that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Best thing to do would be to change the names of each group to be unique.
2. Second best would be to group them by form like you have done, and add the return false.
3. Third best would be to block form submission using jquery 'preventdefault' (which could work for all forms given a particular id).
4. Last (and the most ridiculous option) would be to send each group of buttons to it's own small html file and use iframes to display them on the same page.

Comment: Ended up leaving the text input out of the form and adding a submit handler.